# Linux device driver: is the code shared between multiple devices using the same driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

let's imagine we have some simple linux device driver, with:

```
static const struct of_device_id driver_match[] = {
     { .compatible = "vendor,device1" },
     { .compatible = "vendor,device2" },
     {},
};
```

so that `device1` and `device2` will bind to the same driver. We also have the following function inside the driver:

```
static int some_function(int never_mind)
{
    static int count = 0;
    // print "count" to the logs
    ....
}
```

which is invoked couple of times during `probe()` function of the device. Let's assume that devices are initialized "in the same time". 
My question is how it would work? Will `device1` and `device2` use the same `some_function` object and the same `count` variable or will they get completely different instances?

Is there some good source/book available about how actually the linux driver/module is executed? I could only find many tutorials about "How to write drivers".

And I apologize that I have to ask this question instead of preparing basic driver and check this myself, but I'm waiting for my first linux-capable SoC and could not resist getting this knowledge faster :(

Comment: *"Let's assume that devices are initialized "in the same time"."* -- Faulty assumption. The init routines of built-in modules are executed one at a time by the Linux kernel.  Refer to **do_initcalls()** in [**init/main.c**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L840).  
Only a single processor (of a SMP system) will be active during this phase of booting.  *"We also have the following function inside the driver:"* -- Properly-written routines in a device driver should be serially reusable code so that more than one instance of the device can be supported.

Comment: It's not exactly faulty assumption. You have to correct it to 'that devices **managed by the same driver**'. You may refer to `__device_attach_async_helper()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Will device1 and device2 use the same some_function object and the same count variable or will they get completely different instances?

Yes, they will use the same function and data.  The Linux kernel is a monolithic kernel where all symbols (drivers and core functionality) are loaded into memory in which every other part of the kernel has access.  Init/probe can happen on different cores, so you'll need to properly protect or atomically access any shared data.  In your example, a simple atomic increment/decrement would do the trick.